# passing enums by ref in java

Tags: java, enums, pass-by-reference

How can i pass enum parameter by reference in java? Any solution?

Comment: The normal reason to "pass an argument by reference" is that you want to modify it. You can do this usually in Java because variables are in fact references - however modifying an enum is generally a very bad idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java you cannot pass any parameters by reference.

The only workaround I can think of would be to create a wrapper class, and wrap an enum.

```
public class EnumReference {
    public YourEnumType ref;
}
```

And then you would use it like so:

```
public void someMethod(EnumReference reference) {
    reference.ref = YourEnumType.Something;
}
```

Now, reference will contain a different value for your enum; essentially mimicking pass-by-reference.

Comment: I actually created a generic `IndirectReference<E>` type specifically for this kind of thing. I got tired of passing arrays around.

Comment: @Jon, good call.  I don't usually seem to have a problem with pass-by-value.  Never seems to get in my way.

Comment: @Jonathan: You could also use `AtomicReference`.

Comment: @ColinD I don't generally need the atomicity. Good idea, though, thanks.

Comment: @Nick, well if the effect you want is that a reference is changed, then the return type wouldn't be as helpful as actually changing the reference.

Answer (score 15):

Java is pass by value - always.

You pass references, not objects.  References are passed by value.

You can change the state of a mutable object that the reference points to in a function that it is passed into, but you cannot change the reference itself.